# If $x^2+1/x^2=83$, find the value of $x-1/x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^2+1/x^2=83$, find the value of $x-$$\frac1x$

I tried the following,

As we know, $(a+b)^2=a^2-b^2+2ab$

Therefore, $(x^2+1/x^2)^2$$=(x^2)^2-(1/x^2)^2-2(x^2*1/x^2)$

$\rightarrow$$(83)^2$$=x^4-1/x^4-2x^2/x^2$   (Canceling $x^2$)

$\rightarrow$$x^4-1/x^4=6919-2=6917$

Now, what should I do? Please help. I am stuck.

Comment: $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 +2ab$ not $a^2 - b^2 +2ab$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $$(x-1/x)^2=x^2+1/x^2-2$$ so $(x-1/x)^2=81.$